# Cannot load website with pound in URL using WinHttpRequest

Tags: autohotkey, winhttp, winhttprequest

```
path := "https://test.com/#query=" + target
formMethod := "GET"
fromData := ""

HttpObj := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HttpObj.Open(formMethod,path)
HttpObj.Send(fromData)
```

I try to access a website with a # in the URL. However, the website I get is one without the #, so just https://test.com/query=... I have tried %23 instead of the #, but it is ignored the same way as a #. Is there a simple way to fix this? The variable is correct, but the accessed URL isn't right.

Comment: Can you try with the escape character `#, or put it in braces {#}?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, one of these should work:

```
path := "https://test.com/`#query=" + target
```

or

```
path := "https://test.com/{#}query=" + target
```

But let us know . . .